# compare a list in a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have to compare the keys of a dictionary with a list.

```
l = {"Carlos": 1131577, "Rodrigo": 3250239, "Marisol": 1174787}
```

with the words in

```
d = "Carlos Marisol"
```

For each word in the string that appears in the dictionary, I would like to add up the corresponding values.

The output should be something like this:

```
2306364
Carlos Marisol
```

The code I made is as follows:

```
l = {"Carlos": 1131577, "Rodrigo": 3250239, "Marisol": 1174787}
d = "Carlos Marisol"
a = d.split(' ')
n = 0
h = ""
f = len(a)
for k, v in l.items():
    if k == a[0] or k == a[1]:
        n += v
        h += k + " "
print(n)
print(h)
```

The output is as follows:

```
2306364
Carlos Marisol
```

As you can see it works, but MANUALLY so to speak.

```
if k == a[0] or k == a[1]:
```

The variable `a` : `a[0]`, `a[1]` must be iterable according to its positions, because adding another data does not work, how can I do it?

Because with this data it does not work correctly:

```
l = {"Rodrigo": 2155029, "Sebastian": 3290180, "Camilo": 4271313, "Marisol": 2964688}
d = "Marisol Sebastian Ana Camilo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
l = {"Rodrigo": 2155029, "Sebastian": 3290180, "Camilo": 4271313, "Marisol": 2964688}
d = "Marisol Sebastian Ana Camilo"
a = d.split(' ')
n = 0
h = ""
for b in a:
    if (b in l): 
        n += l[b]
        h += b + " "
print(n)
print(h)
```

Comment: thank you very much, now it is clearer to me

Answer (score 6):

You are using dictionaries backwards. Dictionaries are something to use for lookup, lists are to iterate. There are many ways of handling the case of missing keys.

In the examples below, I'm using the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function rather than writing a loop like

```
n = 0
for w in d.split():
    n += d.get(w, 0)
```

If all your names are in the dictionary, you can do direct lookup:

```
sum(l[w] for w in d.split())
```

If, on the other hand, your names aren't guaranteed to be in `l` you can use `l.get`:

```
sum(l.get(w, 0) for w in d.split())
```

This will return `10526181` for your second example.

Another way is to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for `l`, since the default `int` is 0:

```
l = collections.defaultdict(int, l)
sum(map(l.__getitem__, d.split()))
```

This `sum` formulation is equivalent to the first one, but does not crash on missing names because of the `defaultdict`.

---

To get a string with all the names in the dictionary, you can use a simple one-liner:

```
' '.join(w for w in d.split() if w in l)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
' '.join(filter(l.__contains__, d.split()))
```

Comment: colletions -> collections

Comment: @MadPhysicist hey a question:

l = {"Rodrigo": 2155029, "Sebastian": 3290180, "Camilo": 4271313, "Marisol": 2964688}        how do i order this by console ?

Comment: @MaicolRojas. Console?

Comment: @MadPhysicist i.e. the dictionary must be entered by the user.

Comment: @MadPhysicist would no longer be : l = {"Rodrigo": 2155029, "Sebastian": 3290180, "Camilo": 4271313, "Marisol": 2964688} ("static") L = imput()  to be entered by the user

Comment: @MadPhysicist or how do I make it enter everything from l in a list and then convert it into a dictionary? l = ''{"Julio": 3602258, "Camilo": 2253174, "Rodrigo": 3412013}' List now to dictionary: ...

Comment: @MaicolRojas. This is something that's been asked many times on stack overflow. Try searching "python input dictionary from command line" or similar

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I found the solution, as it is Json, in the imput I ask them to enter the json and then I use list2 = json.load(list1) 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just change `if k == a[0] or k == a[1]:` to

```
if k in a:
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first names are unique in l and in d

```
total = 0
first_names = d.split(" ")
for first_name in first_names:
    if first_name in list(l.keys()):
        total += l[first_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

use comprehension, something like:

```
existing_words = [k for k, _ in l if k in d]
result_num = 0
result_str = ''
for word in existing_words:
    result_num += l[word]
    result_str += word + ' '

print(result_num)
print(d)
```